# PhpStorm is not wrapping long lines

Tags: phpstorm, word-wrap

I have reinstalled PHPStorm and adjusted the wrapping and right margin but seems it's not working what's it I'm missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard wrap (your 2nd screenshot) is about inserting an actual line break in your long line when doing Code Reformat action or on typing (there is separate option for that). The soft wrap (1st and 2rd screenshots), is about virtual wrapping to prevent horizontal scrolling. **Where is does not work?** What file is that?

Comment: You can always manually enable soft warping for the current file via `Main Menu | View | Active Editor | Soft Wrap` (should also be accessible via gutter context menu -- the area where line numbers are).

Comment: @LazyOne that's a php file and code goes beyond the right margin. You can always manually enable soft warping for the current file via ```` Main Menu | View | Active Editor | Soft Wrap ````  works but I have to do it in every file so I was looking for an automatic option. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to fix your Soft Wrap settings. From what I see from your first screenshot you have made an error in the list of "wrap by default" extensions: they should be separated by the semicolon `;` but I see a comma `,` there: `... ; *.adoc, *.php`.

P.S. If you do not care about specific extensions / or to enable Soft Wraps by default for ALL files, just enter `*` in that field.

---

Side note: You can always manually enable soft warping for the current file via `Main Menu | View | Active Editor | Soft Wrap` (should also be accessible via gutter context menu: the area where line numbers are)